# ViewPager event give me error when logout from user

Tags: java, android, events, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app with LoginActivity and MainActivity.
and in my MainActivity I have three fragments. In one of them (UsersFragemnt) I can see all the users that registred to the app.
This is working fine but when I logout I get an error from this fragment.
I searched for a souluton and found that this is becuase the event is still runnning even when I go to LoginActivity so it gives me null and error.
The soultion was to put `(Activity)getContext()` before the event and it worked, but now suddnely I'm getting this error again and it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
Does anyone know why?

This is my `UsersFragemnt` where the problem happing:

```
public void onStart() {                                                                                                                 
    super.onStart();                                                                                                                    

    usersList.clear();                                                                                                                  

        mFiresrote.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener((Activity)getContext(),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {                  
            @Override                                                                                                                   
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {               

                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {                                                
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {                                                                   

                        String user_id = doc.getDocument().getId();                                                                     

                        Users users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);                                          
                        usersList.add(users);                                                                                           

                        usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

my `ProfileFragemnt` code(where is my logout button)

```
mLogoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                        mAuth.signOut();
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(container.getContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
```

and this is my error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference
                      at dim.aviv.projectldogma.UsersFragment$1.onEvent(UsersFragment.java:75)
                      at dim.aviv.projectldogma.UsersFragment$1.onEvent(UsersFragment.java:71)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add null check

```
@Override                                                                                                                   
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {  
   if(queryDocumentSnapshots == null){
       return;
   }
   for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
```

Other way you can add below check as well

```
if (e != null) {
   return;
}
```